# How to restrict SSL/TLS protocol from 1.2 version for google managed ssl in standard app engine

Tags: ssl, google-app-engine

We would like to improve security for our app, so we want to restrict SSL/TLS protocol 1.2 or higher version.

Our app detail:

- Standard App Engine
- Configured Custom Domain
- Use Google Managed SSL certification
- Not use Load Balancer

For the current config, the app engine supports  ['TLS_1_3', 'TLS_1_2', 'TLS_1_0', 'TLS_1_1'] protocols.

We want to keep it simple, so don't want to use Load Balancer or self managed ssl certification.

Is there any solutions for this case?

Comment: Did you manage it?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Google-managed certificates, to change the minimum TLS version or restrict some cipher sets, then you'll have to contact Google Cloud Platform Support to ask for that change.

Refer to this [link](https://cloud.google.com/support-hub#section-2) and click 'File a case' to ask for these changes.